Get the exact lat/lon, in some projection e.g. EPSG:4326, of each SMAP pixel in an image
Description
I am extracting one single image from the image collection ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007") and clipping it with some ee.Geometry.Rectangle. When exporting with Export.image.toDrive the resulting image depends on my scale parameter (m/px). This makes sense of course, but my AOI (rectangle) is only 1x1km compared to SMAP L4's 9x9km resolution, so it overlaps with either 1, 2 or 4 SMAP pixels.
Goal
I realise that all I need is the distance from the middle of my rectangle to the center of the 4 closest pixels, and the value of those 4 pixels (in this case sm_surface) but I am finding that fiendishly hard to compute.
Attempt
The closest I've come to a solution that might work is

Reading up on the EASE 2.0 grid that SMAP L4 is projected on here: nsidc table 3 and 4
Using the python package ease_grid to get the lat/lon coordinates of the EASE 2.0 9km grid (also downloaded them crom nsidc in netCDF format: NSIDC0772_LatLon_EASE2_M09km_v1.0.nc)
Seeing if they line up with the SMAP image. Then I could just, for a given rectangle center, find the closest 4 points on that grid locally and ask GEE for the sm_surface value at those points

However as you can see below, these grid points don't line up with the pixel centers, although the longitudes seem to be in "phase with" the pixels:

I did remember to transform the EASE 2.0 gridpoints from EPSG:6933 to EPSG:4326 using GDAL. Well not at first but now I have :)

The answer is in the sample method which has the geometries parameter which (from documentation) If true, adds the center of the sampled pixel as the geometry property of the output feature. Otherwise, geometries will be omitted (saving memory).
Thank you Ujaval Gandhi, you are a life saver.

// Load the Level 3 SMAP soil moisture product
var soilMoisture = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007")
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_date, end_date))
  .limit(1, 'system:time_start', false)
  .select(['sm_surface','sm_rootzone'])
  .first()
  .clip(aoi);

var samples = soilMoisture.sample({
  region: aoi,
  geometries: true
})

Map.addLayer(samples, {color: 'blue'}, 'Pixel Centers')
//Map.addLayer(multipoints);

Eureka:

Now i have but to download the features and do the final simple computations locally.
